# "Nested" Ampscript - is this possible?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have, out of curiosity, done some testing of dynamically including ampscript values in emails. The aim was to see if it was possible to include content, which itself had ampscript in it.

Example:
"The footer text goes here: %%footer_text%%"

The value of footer_text could include another personalisation:
"Hi, %%firstname%% - manage your account here"

However, as expected, the end result is:
"The footer text goes here: Hi, %%firstname%% - manage your account here"

Is it not possible at all, to achieve this kind of "nested" personalisation? Could SSJS come in handy/be considered?

Best regards
Lukas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this with AMPscript. You will need to use the [TreatAsContent()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/treatascontent.htm) AMPscript function which treats the string as though it had come in from a content area. You can simply write:

```
%%=TreatAsContent(footer_text)=%%
```

However, I would advise that you contain your DE field name in an AttributeValue function, which is a best practice, as if the attribute is missing from the email context (for example, it's not in the Sendable Data Extension), then the email won't error. This can be expressed as:

```
%%=TreatAsContent(AttributeValue('footer_text'))=%%
```

Comment: TreatAsContent or storing the script in a contentblock (content builder) or contentarea (classic builder) and calling in via AMPScript - https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions2/